# Shifting basic footnotes to the right side of a Latex presentation

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, footnotes

I'm using the "Modern Beamer Theme", by Matthias Vogelgesang for a presentation. Trying to shift the footnotes to the right side of the slide. I'd like for the footnotes to read left to right as usual, but anchored to the right side of the page, so the last word "1999" is the same distance from the right edge of the slide as the word "Weiss" currently is now.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{m}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{minted}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
\kern -3pt
\hrule width \textwidth height 0pt
\kern 3pt
}

\usemintedstyle{trac}

\title{Here's a title}
\subtitle{}
\date{Today}
\author{An Author}
\institute{University of Latex}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Footnotes!}

Here is some text. 
\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{Weiss 2010, Vogelgesang 2015, Smith 1999}
\end{frame}
```

[image: Footnotes slide]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) "inner theme" dictates the style of the frame elements traditionally set in the "body" of each slide. This includes the footnotes.

Viewing [`beamerinnerthememetropolis.dtx`](https://github.com/matze/mtheme/blob/master/source/beamerinnerthememetropolis.dtx), we see

```
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \parindent 0em\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \usebeamercolor{footnote}\hbox to 0.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
}
```

which sets the footer using `\raggedright` (or flush left). Let's change that to

```
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \parindent 0em\noindent%
  \raggedleft%\raggedright
  \usebeamercolor{footnote}\hbox to 0.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
}
```

That is, add the above code to your preamble after setting `\usetheme{m}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{m}% https://github.com/matze/mtheme

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \parindent 0em\noindent%
  \raggedleft%\raggedright
  \usebeamercolor{footnote}\hbox to 0.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
\kern -3pt
\hrule width \textwidth height 0pt
\kern 3pt
}

\title{Here's a title}
\subtitle{}
\date{Today}
\author{An Author}
\institute{University of Latex}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Footnotes!}

  Here is some text. 
  \let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{Weiss 2010, Vogelgesang 2015, Smith 1999}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. Misunderstood how "ragged right" and "ragged left" worked before. Thanks!